# How to map a Java Map to Object using Orika

Tags: java, orika

I am trying to map a Java Map to a POJO but having problems with using Orika.

I have a LinkedHashMap and trying to map it to a POJO.  I've been reading this website https://www.baeldung.com/orika-mapping, specifically section 4.2

This is how I define my orika mapper:

```java
factory.classMap(Map.class, TestDto.class)
                .field("nest['name']", "name")
                .toClassMap();
```

and this is the LinkedHashMap I'm trying to map:

```java
Map<Object, Object> nest = new LinkedHashMap<>();
nest.put("name", "myname");

Map<Object, Object> obj = new LinkedHashMap<>();
obj.put("nest", nest);
```

and this is the POJO I'm trying to map to:

```java
public class TestDto {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

when I do:

```java
TestDto testDto = mapper.map(obj, TestDto.class);
```

I get null as name. Is this scenario possible to map or do I have to do more customization of orika?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the name will return null for this mapping.
`TestDto testDto = mapper.map(obj, TestDto.class);`

This is due to variable name in TestDto class does not contain variable name nest.

To map your POJO with different key.
Pleas add @JsonProperty in your get() method.

Example:

```
@JsonProperty("nest")
public String getName() { return name; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can define a mapper like:

```java
factory.classMap(Map.class, TestDto.class)
                .field("nest:{get('nest')|type=Map}.name:{get('name')|type=java.lang.String}", "name")
                .toClassMap();
```

which is outlined here:
https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html

This is really only needed if you don't have control over the Pojo and/or do not want to make a copy of the Pojo